# I want the values in the ArrayList to show once a button is pressed

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

Once a button is clicked, I get a `NullPointerException` where I expected the value in the `ArrayList` to be printed on screen. For instance, if I click a button pointing to "A", "A" will be displayed on screen, if I click a button pointing to "B", "B" will be printed on screen.

```
public class Media extends JPanel {

    //Declares our media player component
    private JPanel video_pnl, control_pnl;
    private JButton play_btn;
    private JLabel loc_lbl;
    private int increment;
    ArrayList<String> file_location;

    public Media(ArrayList<String> file_location) {
        this.file_location = file_location;
        increment = 0;
        while (increment < file_location.size()) {
            video_pnl = new JPanel();
            video_pnl.setLayout(new BoxLayout(video_pnl, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            loc_lbl = new JLabel();
            loc_lbl.setText(file_location.get(increment));
            play_btn = new JButton("Play");
            control_pnl = new JPanel();
            control_pnl.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
            play_btn.setActionCommand("play");
            video_pnl.add(loc_lbl);
            control_pnl.add(play_btn);
            video_pnl.add(control_pnl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            Handler handler = new Handler();
            play_btn.addActionListener(handler);

            video_pnl.revalidate();
            add(video_pnl);
            increment++;
        }
    }

    private class Handler implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getActionCommand().equals("play")) {
                play();
            }
    //            if (e.getSource() == play_btn){
    //                play();
    //            }
        }
    }

    public void play() {
        for (int i = 0; i < file_location.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(file_location.get(i));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Declare and initialize local variables
        ArrayList<String> file_location = new ArrayList<>();
        file_location.add("A");
        file_location.add("B");
        file_location.add("C");
        file_location.add("D");
        file_location.add("E");

        //creates instances of the VlcPlayer object, pass the mediaPath and invokes the method "run"
        Media mediaplayer = new Media(file_location);
        JFrame ourframe = new JFrame();
        ourframe.setContentPane(mediaplayer);
        ourframe.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
        ourframe.setSize(300, 560);
        ourframe.setVisible(true);
        ourframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well *where* is the exception being thrown? Please post the full stack trace, and indicate the relevant lines within your code. (We can probably guess, but *please* provide complete information to make everyone's life simpler - read http://tinyurl.com/so-list)

Answer (score 2):

Add:

```
this.file_location = file_location;
```

into your constructor (under this line: public Media(ArrayList file_location) {)

Comment: hey, thankks for your correction, but when i click any play button, all the letters in the arraylist displays, but i want a single letter pointing to the button to be displayed. thanks for d correction though

Comment: Then you need to change this part:    'for (int i = 0; i < file_location.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(file_location.get(i));
        }' To do something else, as currently it is just being told to print out everything in the list.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor, you refer to the argument `file_location` to build your panels, but you never store the array in your class variable. Since it is initialized to `null` by default, you get the NPE when you refer to it in the `play ()` method.

Initialize your class member in your constructor with the argument's value (`this.file_location = file_location`), it will fix your problem.

On a side note, I suggest you use argument names that are not already used for class members. It becomes easier when reading the code to notice if you are referring to the argument or the member, and will prevent the problem you have just observed.

Comment: hey, thankks for your correction, but when i click any play button, all the letters in the arraylist displays, but i want a single letter pointing to the button to be displayed. thanks for d correction though – MastaOpec just now

Comment: When you call the `play ()` method, you don't specify which element should be displayed. The `for` loop you have coded will go through _all_ of the elements in the array and print them all. You have to store somewhere the button that was pressed.